# How to stop mobile browser url redirect in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I am new to prestashop and I installed it on my local server then I uploaded the site to my online server and I tried to access the site from mobile browser, the browser redirected me to wrong url (localhost/prestashop). How to fix this or how to stop mobile browser detection and redirect to the main theme?

Comment: Flush cache. Regenerate .htaccess (disable/enable friendly URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not use a separate mobile theme you need to go to `Back office > Preferences > Themes` and under `Mobile` tab where it says **Enable mobile theme** select **I'd like to disable it**. That will display your main theme on all devices.

And it is a bit strange you had that redirect. So check `Back office > Preferences > SEO & URLs` under **SET SHOP URL** that it has the right URL. Or maybe regenerate the `.htaccess` by disabling and enabling **Friendly URL** option.